# Object remains undefined even though it's stored in a global

Tags: javascript

I'm building pong and creating a paddle in an initialize method however, the paddle remains undefined even when it is stored as a global variable. I have also tried making it a property of 'window'.  I don't actually want to store it as a global, but I cannot figure out why it remains undefined.

```
var startBtn = $('#startBtn');

startBtn.on("click", function() {
  initialize();
});

var initialize = function() {
  paddleOne = {
   x: 20,
   y1: 200,
   y2: 270,
   setPaddle: drawPaddle(this.x, this.y1, this.y2),
   translateUp: function() {
    var new_y1 = this.y1 + 10;
    drawPaddle(this.x, new_y1, this.y2);
  }
};

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 49) {
    event.preventDefault();
    paddleOne.translateUp();
};
```

Shouldn't the properties of the object be available throughout my js file?

**Edit:**

I have attempted to store the function of drawPaddle as a property on the paddleOne object in case there was some problem with the ordering of function calls:

```
paddleOne = {
  x: 20,
  y1: 200,
  y2: 270,
  drawPaddle: function () {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x, this.y1);
    context.lineTo(this.x, this.y2);
    context.stroke();
  },
  translateUp: function() {
    var new_y1 = this.y1 + 10;
    this.drawPaddle(this.x, new_y1, this.y2);
  },
  translateDown: function() {
    var new_y2 = this.y2 + 10;
    this.drawPaddle(this.x, this.y1, new_y2);
  }
};
```

**What I ended up doing is inadvisable and I'd like to know the right way.  What I did was remove the document.ready function declaration around my js file and then put the script loading tag at the bottom of the html file.  It works mostly although it now knows of the paddle object but not of any of its properties but I feel like it's very bad practice. However, this will be on the only js file in the project.**

Comment: are you using `use strict`?

Comment: I just enabled it.  Same problem.

Comment: remove it, i don't see why your code isn't working. why don't you want to use `var`? btw, add `console.log(windows);` at the end of initialize func; do you see your paddleOne when you use the debugger?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Because I wanted to see if it was a problem with scoping.  If I made it a global and it's still not being picked up, it has to be something else.  I do not know why it is not picking it up.

Comment: you are missing a couple of closing curly braces in there

Comment: Potentially stupid question: do you ever run `initialize()` (by clicking that button or otherwise)?

Comment: Yes, that's when it throws the error. I think the problem has something to do with document.ready that I put at the top.  I hope that isn't a stupid problem but I'm still getting started with js

Comment: And how were we supposed to know there's more code than you provided? Can you show us your **full** code?

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable for the paddle:

```
var paddleOne; // <============ your paddle variable

var startBtn = $('#startBtn');

startBtn.on("click", function() {
  initialize();
});

var initialize = function() {
  paddleOne = {
   x: 20,
   y1: 200,
   y2: 270,
   setPaddle: drawPaddle(this.x, this.y1, this.y2),
   translateUp: function() {
    var new_y1 = this.y1 + 10;
    drawPaddle(this.x, new_y1, this.y2);
  }
};

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 49) {
    event.preventDefault();
    paddleOne.translateUp();
};
```

the `paddleOne` variable will be available everywhere in this code now

Comment: It should work either way. While this would theoretically be better, it shouldn't be the source of the problem.